# Exporting Log to BigQuery (table partitioned) using custom destination sink

Tags: logging, google-bigquery, stackdriver

Hello guys.

I want to create a "sink" (logging service) to export the logs to BigQuery (partitioned table). However, I have not been able to do it, by default it is creating a fragmented table.

I am using "custom destination" and the code I use in the "sink destination" option is:

```
bigquery.googleapis.com/projects/miproyecto/datasets/dataset_organization.
```

PD: I am using the "custom Destination" option because the sinks and the bigQuery tables are in different projects.

Comment: Could you share the error message or any document which you followed to create a sink? Do you assign permission to the service account to write to the sink's export destination? This is google official [document](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2) for your consideration.

Answer (score 0):

For now there is no option to create log-BQ sink with partitioned table in google console and stable *gcloud logging sinks create* command. We have to use *alpha* version of the gcloud command.

```
gcloud alpha logging sinks create <Sink_Name bigquery.googleapis.com/projects/<BQ Project>/datasets/<dataset> --log-filter='<FILTER CONDITION>' --use-partitioned-tables --project <LOG PROJECT>
```

Basically *--use-partitioned-tables* provided in alpha version does the trick. Please refer following link of official google documentation.

Link : https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/logging/sinks/create

I tested it and its working fine for me. Hope the answer is useful!

Regards
Manish